# Mapreduce job getting stuck

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hue

I am new to hadoop. I have installed cloudera hadoop using cloudera manager on ubuntu 12.04. when I tried testing my installation using command given under "testing the installation" documentation of cloudera my mapreduce job gets stuck at accepted stage and never proceeds from there. I have to kill job. Here is the command i am using:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi 10 1
```

In hue job browser, status of the job is accepted.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had also face same issue while running wordCount problem in pseudo distributed mode, the reason i figured out that my hard drive was almost full because of that i was facing this issue. Try cleaning your hard drive. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Salmanbw thanks for replying. but can u tell me what steps you performed to clean your drive. I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: I deleted my unwanted files both from hadoop and local FS and it worked for me.

Comment: hi salman.thanks for quick reply. but in my case issue is something else. i have installed the same on cloud too. there also i am facing the same issue. it gets stuck at this stage:                                                                                         15/04/29 13:59:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1430314779724_0001.Do we need to configure something else also after installation(have installed using cloudera manager) ? after installation i had just logged into hue webui and created a hue super user and after that i tried running Pi estimator.

Comment: Which version of hadoop are you using..??

Comment: Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.0

Comment: did you chmod the jar file (custom one) to 777?

Comment: +1, I am also facing the same issue. I am running sqoop import command on Clodera-quickstart-vm-5.4.2-0 and the job also getting stuck on accepted stage. Help will be appreciated. Thanks